# AVFoundation iOS 5

Tags: iphone, video, mp3, avfoundation, ios5

My apps runing on the appstore are **using mp3 and video files that don't work since iOS5 update**.

I've installed **xcode 4.2** and...
When I test in the **iPhone 5 Simulator** or **device I get the following error** (for audio or video files):

```
Error loading 
System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn:  
dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn, 262): 
Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable
Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
Expected in: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
```

When I try this in the **iPhone 4.3 simulator** or **device it does not crash** ..

I've cleaned and re import the frameworks involved but it seems to be that kind of error

Note: My apps don't use any security.

Could you help?

Answer (score 9):

I just have found an answer [here](https://gist.github.com/1267913).

If your app crashes here, disable All Exceptions in XCode 4 Breakpoints Tab. Maybe it's SDK bug.

Comment: Thanks so much. Worked for me too. Does anyone know why this is the case?

Answer (score 4):

Try to make your player a retained property. I experienced the same and because I declared my player locally I think ARC retained as soon as the method in which I declared the player ran out of scope.

Make player a retained property

```
@property (strong)AVAudioPlayer *player;
```

Remember to set the delegate (self.player.delegate = self) and use the delegate's methods to clean up:

```
-(void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)playedSuccessfully {
    self.player = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution: `NSURL` instead of `NSString`:

```
NSURL *chemin = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/MySound.wav", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];
NSError *error;
AVAudioPlayer* mySound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:chemin error:&error];
mySound.delegate = self;
[chemin release];
[mySound Play];
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, but my code wasn't different from yours. I don't *really* need anything in the Security framework, but adding that framework to my project fixed this issue.