# MPMoviePlayer error loading file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, simulator, mpmovieplayer

I am trying to use the MPMoviePlayer to play a simple movie and I keep getting this error in the console(but the movie is played): 
My xcode version is 4.3.1.

```
2012-03-24 14:51:49.488 european_culture[450:17a07] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable
Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
2012-03-24 14:51:49.496 european_culture[450:17a07] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable
Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
2012-03-24 14:51:49.584 european_culture[450:17a07] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable
Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
2012-03-24 14:51:49.592 european_culture[450:17a07] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable
Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
2012-03-24 14:51:49.610 european_culture[450:17a07] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable
Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
2012-03-24 14:51:49.617 european_culture[450:17a07] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable
Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
2012-03-24 14:51:51.749 european_culture[450:13a03] Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <MPMoviePlayerViewController: 0x935f500>.
2012-03-24 14:51:51.930 european_culture[450:15303] AQMixerDevice::SetMixerChannelLayout(0x7d47f50): scope 1, element 1, layout: tag=0x640001: error -10851
```

But I tested it on my iPad(5.1) and the message was different.(The movie is played, too.)

```
Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <MPMoviePlayerViewController: 0xf6a0c40>.
```

What's the problem? 
Here is my code that should play a movie when my button is pressed:

```
-(void)playMovie:(NSString *)fileName   
{
NSString *movieFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:@"mov"];
NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:movieFile];
MPMoviePlayerViewController *tempMoviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [tempMoviePlayer moviePlayer];

[tempMoviePlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)];
[_zoomImageView addSubview: tempMoviePlayer.view];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:tempMoviePlayer]; 
[self setWantsFullScreenLayout:YES]; 
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(playMovieFinished:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:moviePlayer];
[moviePlayer play];

[fileURL release];
[tempMoviePlayer release];
}
```

plz, help me.
thanks a lot.

Comment: Only regarding the first part: I guess, you have recently updated from Xcode 4.2 to 4.3, and you use an "old" project. As an result, the paths are incorrect, what not really matters, since the frameworks are there anyway.

Comment: ah... I see. thank you for your help.
It's a good thing it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is a confirmed bug of the iOS SDK 5 / Simulator - happens as soon as the simulator tries to play sound (from a movie or any other sound source). Do not worry though, it won't be a problem on the actual device.

You mentioned actual reports of users having trouble using your App - those problems are not related / connected to the issue you have posted above.

This issue is filed by Apple under Bug ID# 10555404. I did file a report myself which has finally been identified as a dupe of the mentioned bug id.

The issue currently persists up until and including Xcode Version 4.3.2 (4E2002), iOS SDK 5.1.

may be This Problem May occur if you incorrectly import a Mac OSX framework instead of iOs framework. Removing the Mac OS framework worked for me.

Remember to set the delegate (self.player.delegate = self) and use the delegate's methods to clean up:

```
-(void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)playedSuccessfully 
 {
       self.player = nil;
 }
```

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8317546/932011)

Comment: It's an SDK bug with the Simulator. If you disable exception breakpoints or just keep going through them then it'll actually all work OK. Everything works fine on the device.

Comment: Oh!! thank you so much!!
OK. I'll check which framework I imported.
And I'll set the delegate. 
thanks a lot!! :D

Comment: When i´m testing my scene on the simulator, the video and sound disappears after few seconds. On the device i get the same buggy result...(Tested with the latest Xcode version 4.3.2)

Comment: Did he copied from there ;) !?? @bobobobo Then what about this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/9055916/1059705