# What Is the Easiest way to Play Sound on the Iphone?

Tags: iphone

What Is the Easiest way to Play Sound on the Iphone? I have an mp3 file, I'd rather keep it and not convert it to other format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this turned out to be quite a mess, but I found a solution. I'm running XCode 4.4.1.

Here are the steps that worked for me:

1. Drag mp3 file from finder into XCode project -> Supporting Files. Make sure to copy the file. let's assume the file name is sound.mp3.
2. Add AVFoundation framework to your project.
3. ## import < AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
4. @property (strong) AVAudioPlayer* soundPlayer;
5. use the following code to init the player and play the mp3:
   NSURL *chemin = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/sound.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];
   NSError *error;
   self.soundPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:chemin error:&error];
   [self.soundPlayer play];

Now at this point, I got an exception which is described here: [AVFoundation iOS 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7779851/avfoundation-ios-5)
In short it means that there is probably a bug in the simulator which shouldn't happen on the device. In my case I turned all exception on, which stopped my code from executing. What you should do is to remove the option of throwing all exceptions.

In addition, in my case it's 3-5 seconds until it first play the sound, so be patient when you don't get the sound right away. After it play for the first time, it will play instantly.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way I know of to play an MP3 file is to use the `AVAudioPlayer` class. Basically, just do (skipping error checking, setting delegate for detecting completion, etc):

```
NSURL* soundUrl = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"soundFile" withExtension:@"mp3"];
AVAudioPlayer* player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundUrl error:&err];
[player play];
```

Comment: +1 Probably the easiest way to play audio, I just made a slight tweak to make this easier to understand for those new to iOS.

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work, it throws me an exception which I can't see exactly as it gets to the assembly.

Comment: yes, I have. here the code: NSError *error;
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:@"/soundFile.mp3"];
    AVAudioPlayer* player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
    [player play];

Comment: @NSPostWhenIdle, yes, I have imported the AVFoundation framework, and added the header file <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

Comment: @kernix Get rid of the / it is unnecessary.

Comment: -43 is file not found. Probably you are not getting the path to the sound resource correctly. -See my updated answer.- @NSPostWhenIdle beat me to it, thanks! :)

Comment: OK, I followed the updated answer, now I get: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-50 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -50.)"

Comment: I copied it to the xcode under Supporting Files I added new group named sound and copied it there.

Comment: @kernix Check the updated answer again, specifically make sure you use  `URLForResource`, instead of trying to create the URL from a string.

Comment: I checked the updated answer and used it and now I get an exception, with no detail.

Comment: @kernix delete the .mp3 from your project then add it again. BE SURE TO CHECK BOTH BOXES

Comment: @NSPostWhenIdle I even opened a new project and tried it - now I get this long log: PlayMP3[96946:1b03] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
  Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhon

Comment: AppleHDAHALPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
  Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security

Comment: @kernix I don't believe these errors have anything to do with the audio player. They are referencing Security.framework.

Comment: this error occurs after calling [player play];  - If I comment this line of code, I don't get the error.

Comment: Got this thing working. This is a bug in Xcode: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7779851/avfoundation-ios-5

Answer (score 1):

First add AVFoundation Framework to the project [Goto Target> Right click on project>Build Phases>Link Binary with Library> Click on +> select AVFoundation> Add]

```
// get file path
NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: fileNameToPlay ofType:@"mp3"];

// allocate and refer to file
AVAudioPlayer *player =[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath: soundPath] error: NULL];

// set delegate
player. delegate = self; 

// play
[player play];
```